# Is this called "a dial" or a "knob"?

Tags: word-usage

There is a round control object on some electronic equipment  such as a fan

[image]

When I talk to my children, I don't know if I say "**Please turn the dial anticlockwise to turn down the fan**" or "**Please turn the knob anticlockwise to turn down the fan**"?

Comment: A 'dial' is an output device for displaying information, or a graduated control for an instrument. Even if the fan has some speed settings marked, I would call it a control or a knob. Aside: I would not use the word 'turn' twice in the sentence: "Turn the knob anticlockwise to slow down the fan" or "Twist the knob anticlockwise to turn down the fan".

Comment: Either is acceptable. These are often synonymous.  Note also that "Ex" is not the abbreviation for "for example" in English. The abbreviation is "e.g." - from Latin "exempli gratia".

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a 'knob' is just the part of a dial you grip and turn, so it could be called either - however, not every knob is a dial.

A dial has marked gradations or settings that the knob turns and selects. The knob may even have a 'needle', or indicator that points to each setting and may even click into each position. So if your fan has several settings, such as 'off', 'low', 'medium' and 'high', and the knob is used to select these then you have a dial.

Some knobs do not have a pointer or specific settings to point to. For example, some gas appliances may have a knob that increases or decreases the gas flow in an analogue fashion. We would not consider these a 'dial'.

Answer (score -1):

> A knob is a rotary device used for controlling the input of an electrical or mechanical machine. It is used as a regulator in mechanical and electrical devices. A dial is a mechanical device used to show the recording of the measurement on the display of the device. [Source](https://homework.study.com/explanation/what-are-five-examples-of-devices-that-use-dials-and-knobs.html)

Similar to what @Weather_Vane has mentioned in the comments, I would use "knob" as well.

But both are actually usable in this situation.

Comment: +1 Agreed. I'd also add that a "dial" gives the impression of the ability to fine tune the levels, but a fan usually has three or four possible settings, so "dial" doesn't work as well

Comment: Also, the traditional hand-turned controls for hi-fi, tv, oven etc could be called dials, but are more usually knobs.

Comment: Homework Study dot Com?? AmE speaker here.   Exactly the opposite for me. I would *always* call that a *dial* and would *never* call it a *knob*.  A knob is what is attached to my cupboard door to help me open it.  *Grab the cupboard door by the knob and pull.*  A dial is *always* a device that can be turned to increase or decrease something.  There is a tuning and a volume dial on a radio.  Consider the phrase *dial it up*, which means *increase it*.

Comment: @EllieK I'm also an AmE speaker too ;P

Comment: Use of dial as an input device is attested here https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dial and here https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dial  (I don't know how to include links in comments, sorry). Notably also in phrases like 'dial a number (rotate a dial on the face of an old-style phone)' or 'dial in on the station' with a radio. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: as usual, these online sites are hyper restrictive to the point of failure. See, for example, "Don't touch that dial" It is too restrictive re: knobs as well.

Comment: To clarify, knob is definitely appropriate in the situation as well, and probably the word I would use, but dial is completely appropriate too.